# Error message from previous request is popping up whenever the user types in input field -[ redux with useselector]

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks, redux-saga

Below is a snippet which I'm using to implement login functionality with redux and saga, I'm using the functional component. The problem is if I enter the wrong password and email saga triggers an error and the redux action is set to log in error and in the component using selectors I'm able to catch it and show it as an error(I'm using a general toast android component for showing errors) But after this step, if the user start's typing new email or password in the input field, the error message from previous requests again starts popping up without even pressing the login button. What is the better way to clear an error message from the state, once it is shown?

**Login.js**

```
function Login({ navigation }, props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // Application states
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');
  const [emailColor, setEmailColor] = React.useState('black');
  const [passwordColor, setpasswordColor] = React.useState('black');

  //selectors
  const loginSelector = useSelector(state => state.login);
  console.log('selector resp ==>', loginSelector);
  if (loginSelector.error && !loginSelector.loading) {
    console.log(loginSelector.error_message);
    danger(loginSelector.error_message);
  }
  //selector end

  //func start
  const checkLogin = () => {
    setEmailColor('#000');
    setpasswordColor('#000');
    if (!validation.isEmail(email)) {
      warning('Invalid Email');
      setEmailColor('red');
      return;
    } else if (validation.isEmpty(password)) {
      warning('Invalid Password');
      setpasswordColor('red');
      return;
    } else {
      dispatch(userLogin(email, password));
    }
  };
  //func end
  
  return (
    <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} >
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.topArea}>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.middleArea}>
          <View style={[styles.loginColumn, styles.centralize]}>
            <Text style={styles.loginImage}>trōc</Text>

            <MaterialIconTextbox
              handler={setEmail}
              type="email"
              icon="email-outline"
              label="Email"
              statusColor={emailColor}
              style={styles.loginFields}
            />
            <MaterialIconTextbox
              handler={setPassword}
              type="password"
              icon="pencil-box-outline"
              label="Password"
              statusColor={passwordColor}
              style={styles.loginFields}
              secure={true}
            />
            <Text />
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.bottomArea}>
          <View style={styles.centralize}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.loginButton}
              onPress={checkLogin}>
              <Text style={styles.loginButtonText}>Login</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.loginButtonGoogle}
              onPress={() => onGoogleButtonPress()}>
              <Text style={styles.loginButtonText}>Sign in with google</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.topMargin}
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Signup')}>
              <Text style={styles.signupText}>New? Signup</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.topMargin}
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Forgot')}>
              <Text style={styles.forgotText}>Forgot password.</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            {/* <Text>{users.error_message}</Text> */}
          </View>
        </View>
       
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
export default Login;
```

**loginReducer.js**

```
import {LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_ERROR} from '../../utils/Constants';
import {danger} from '../../utils/Notification';
import initialState from './initialState';
export default function loginReducer(state = initialState.login, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: false,
        loading: false,
        ...action,
      };
    case LOGIN_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: true,
        loading: false,
        ...action,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated :)

**Update**
I came up with two solutions, but which one is better, I'm not able to figure out

first is

```
 if (loginSelector.error && !loginSelector.loading) {
    console.log(loginSelector.error_message);
    danger(loginSelector.error_message);
    dispatch(clearLoginError());
  }
```

second is

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (loginSelector.error && !loginSelector.loading) {
      danger(loginSelector.error_message);
      dispatch(clearLoginError());
    }
  }, [loginSelector.error, loginSelector.loading]);
```

Can you folks help me out

Answer (score 0):

So I believe both the methods are ok to change a state in redux, the one without using useEffect and the one with useEffect

```
if (loginSelector.error && !loginSelector.loading) {
    console.log(loginSelector.error_message);
    danger(loginSelector.error_message);
    dispatch(clearLoginError());
  }

and 

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (loginSelector.error && !loginSelector.loading) {
      danger(loginSelector.error_message);
      dispatch(clearLoginError());
    }
  }, [loginSelector.error, loginSelector.loading]);
```